# deleter decorator en @property

Tags: python, python-3.x

En la siguiente clase, ¿qué objeto tiene del deleter decorator?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicarte un poco más? Es obvio decirte que se usa para implementar el *delete* de la propiedad (`del c.x`). Pero tampoco es cuestión de explicarte cómo gestiona python los objetos en memoria ni qué es el protocolo *descriptor* que implementa el `property`.

Comment: No soy programador. Uso python para hacer mis pequeñas cosas. En otros foros veo que se recomienda @property frente a
`class C:
    def x(self):
    '''Haz algo.'''`
pero no veo la utilidad de deleter en este ejemplo típico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si *alguien* te recomienda usar `properties` en python, casi seguro que no conoce cómo funciona python o cree que se programa igual que en java. El *estilo pythónico* es ser "explícito" antes que "implícito", y las *properties* van en contra del estilo *pythónico* de hacer las cosas.

Toda la *magia* del mecanismo de herencia de python se debe en gran parte al funcionamiento de los **descriptores**. Todos los métodos que tiene una clase, tanto *explícitos* como *implícitos*, son descriptores y su funcionamiento está cuidadosamente optimizado para que no sobrecargue la ejecución del código. Es así como consigue python que funcione la herencia múltiple, los métodos estáticos y de clase, las metaclases y los decoradores de clase. Consigue que sea simple la inyección de dependencias (*mixins*) o la programación dinámica, por ejemplo. No obstante, aunque los descriptores sean omnipresentes, son totalmente transparentes para el usuario y no se entera de que los está usando.

Podemos definir un **descriptor** como un objeto que tenga al menos uno de estos métodos:

- `__get__` para lectura
- `__set__` para modificación
- `__delete__` para borrado

Estos métodos conforma lo que se denomina **protocolo descriptor** y condicionará el tratamiento que hará de este objeto el intérprete python.

Tenemos dos tipos de descriptores:

- **Descriptor no de datos** (*"Non-data descriptor"*): son los que sólo tiene definido el método `__get__`
- **Descriptor de datos** (*"Data descriptor"*): cuando tienen definido al menos uno de los otros métodos, `__set__` y/o `__delete__`.

Si has mirado la documentación de `property` te sonará mucho, ya que una *property* se construye definiendo estas tres funciones. En definitiva, **una `property` es un descriptor** que implementa los tres métodos y, opcionalmente, define un atributo para la documentación. Por lo tanto, **una *propiedad* es un *descriptor de datos***.

Si te interesa el tema, hace algún tiempo escribí algunos artículos sobre descriptores: http://blog.ch3m4.org/tag/descriptor/

---

**>** Pero vayamos a la pregunta: **¿para qué el `deleter`?**

El primer decorador, `@property`, implementa el método `__get__` del descriptor. Si no hacemos nada más, tendríamos una propiedad de sólo lectura. El resto de métodos del descriptor (`__get__`/`__delete__`) darán error si se invocan.

El decorador `setter` copia la propiedad para sustituir el método `__set__` por el que obtiene del decorador. De este modo, se puede modificar la propiedad.

El último decorador `deleter` serviría para implementar el método `__delete__` del descriptor. Cuando se invoca este método, es la última oportunidad para liberar recursos antes de que desaparezca la propiedad de la instancia.

Hay que tener presente que, mientras que un atributo se define para cada instancia de la clase, la *"propiedad"* es común para todas las instancias. Cuando se invoca el `deleter` no es para liberar todos los recursos que use la propiedad, sino sólo aquellos que sean específicos de la instancia. Y, por supuesto, tampoco sirve para eliminar la propiedad, no es un *"destructor"* del modo que se entiende en otros lenguajes orientados a objetos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. Como ingeniero me atrajo Python por la sencillez de la sintaxis que me permitía concentrarme en el problema de ingeniería más que en el propio código. Creo que le voy a dar una oportunidad al estilo pythónico de definición de funciones.

Comment: Seguro que no te arrepentirás. Todo en python, sobre todo la librería estándar, es un compendio de conocimientos listos para su uso sin preocuparse por la implementación. Ideal para científicos e ingenieros.